# Syntax error near unexpected token 'then' in shell script (Whitespaces are good)

Tags: bash

Shebang is #!/bin/bash
for f in C:"\Users\Sudje\OneDrive\Documents\Aug**"
do if [ "${f}" = "PimsShows.archive" ];
then ./mongorestore.exe -h 127.0.0.1:27017 --archive = "$f" --gzip
fi;
done

I get Syntax error near unexpected token 'then' in shell script. I looked at all the whitespaces already and they are good I think. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You should have either a newline or `;` before the `do`.

```
#                                                  |
#                                                  v
for f in C:"\Users\Sudje\OneDrive\Documents\Aug**" ; do if [ "${f}" = "PimsShows.archive" ]; then ./mongorestore.exe -h 127.0.0.1:27017 --archive = "$f" --gzip;fi;done
#                                                  ^
#                                                  |
```

Or

```
for f in C:"\Users\Sudje\OneDrive\Documents\Aug**"
do 
   if [ "${f}" = "PimsShows.archive" ]
   then
      ./mongorestore.exe -h 127.0.0.1:27017 --archive = "$f" --gzip
   fi
done
```

The code does not do what you think it does. There are three issues.

One, the quoting of `C:"\Users\Sudje\OneDrive\Documents\Aug**"` precludes any glob-pattern expansion. You want the `**` to be outside the quotes, like this: `C:"\Users\Sudje\OneDrive\Documents\Aug\"**`

Second, by default `**` does not recurse into subdirectories. To do that, you must change the default behavior of bash by calling `shopt -s globstar`.

Third, the value of `$f` contains the full path, including the `C:` and all intermediate subdirectories, but you compare it to a filename without the whole path. You need something like `"$(basename "$f")"` instead of `"${f}"`

(EDIT: Added quotes over ${f} below, otherwise filenames with spaces will cause `basename` to fail)

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in C:"\Users\Sudje\OneDrive\Documents\Aug"**
do 
   if [ "$(basename "${f}")" = "PimsShows.archive" ]
   then
      ./mongorestore.exe -h 127.0.0.1:27017 --archive = "$f" --gzip
   fi
done
```

Note, I don't have bash for windows, so I am not 100% confident that `basename` over Windows-style path (with `\`) works well.

A more robust solution, instead of `**` and `shopt` with `basename` is to use `find`:

```
find  "C:"\Users\Sudje\OneDrive\Documents\Aug" -iname "PimsShows.archive" -print0 | \
   xargs -0 -i ./mongorestore.exe -h 127.0.0.1:27017 --archive = {} --gzip
```

Comment: Yes thank you! This worked! But now I don't have output haha

Comment: @Sudjeeni What are you trying to do? Putting the `*` between the double-quotes of the `for` is probably not what you want. I assume that you want to go over all files under `C:\Users\Sudje\OneDrive\Documents` which have `Aug` in the beginning of their name, right? In that case the `*` should be outside and not between the quotes

Comment: no I'm trying to loop over all files in the subfolders in the directory "\Users\Sudje\OneDrive\Documents\Aug". So I put based on an other question in stackoverflow  : for f in C:"\Users\Sudje\OneDrive\Documents\Aug\*\*" . Maybe the if statement is not good

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a semicolon after `gzip`, so the end of the if-clause is not recognised:

```
for f in C:"\Users\Sudje\OneDrive\Documents\Aug**" do 
  if [ "${f}" = "PimsShows.archive" ];
  then ./mongorestore.exe -h 127.0.0.1:27017 --archive = "$f" --gzip;
  fi; 
done
```

In top of this, you did not add a shebang in order to completely analyse this issue.

Comment: I already tried that and it doesn't work.

Comment: I entered your script at [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and this is what came out. Do you know the shebang you need for git bash scripts?

Comment: #!/bin/env mongo
for f in C:"\Users\Sudje\OneDrive\Documents\Aug\*" do if [ "${f}" = "PimsShows.archive" ]; then ./mongorestore.exe -h 127.0.0.1:27017 --archive = "$f" --gzip; fi; done

This is my whole code. The only error is the syntax error

Comment: A comment is not the right place to show code. Please edit the question.

Comment: That shebang seems to be wrong.

Comment: I already changed the shebang and it still gives the syntax error, so it's not the shebang